# Rain Drop Detector

Tags: sensor

The Problem: I tend to open my bedroom windows so that the natural breeze can pass. This is great for cooling but not great when rain falls. If rain falls heavy enough, even if it falls for 1 minute my room (and sometimes my bed) gets soaked. Normally, when I hear the rain fall I would rush over and close the windows, but that does not always happen. I need some sort of alarm that will detect when the rain fall (and when it stops) within 1 minute of it actually falling and stopping. At some point, if I get that system working, I will automate the opening and closing of the windows as rain starts and stops.

**What kind of electronic device should I use?**

So far I have envisioned a humidity sensor paired with a beat detector under a "drum". If humidity is high and there are more than 3 beats per second; its raining close the windows. Is there an actual electronic device that can perform that function?

Comment: Just googled "rain detector". There are many different results.

Comment: I googled it as well, and ones based on conductivity are not suitable.

Comment: what's wrong with the common solution?

Comment: Check out what they use on cars...

Comment: A camera with some software can do this, even from a distance. Look up things like "rain detection in frequency space," for example. You could even achieve this without ANY software at all, if you design an optical system and mask out the uninteresting stuff on the Fourier plane before reaching the detector. For that, consult any good optics book and look for "spatial filtering."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might actually be able to use a thermopile to measure the temperature of the ground and the sky. On even moderately clear and warm days, the difference is +40C. On days with lots of rain and/or cloud, it's 8C or lower.

If you have an IR gun, just point it at the ground and at various points in the sky on various weather conditions to see what you get. Last week on a slightly rainy day I got a 8C difference. It was just raining earlier this morning but it stopped since and right now the difference is 13C. On a sunny coolish, cloudyish day it was 50C and on a bright clear sunny day it was >60C. I couldn't get an exact reading because the sky was so cold that it over-ranged the IR gun.

---

An alternative method that might be more accurate is using thermopiles to measure the temperature of something (something terrestrial, not the sky) far in the distance using two otherwise identical thermopiles, except one has a regular 5.5um longpass filter and the other has a 8-14um filter. The 8-14um device excludes the wavelengths that are absorbed by moisture in the air so it gets a more accurate temperature of the object whereas the 5.5um does not and is affected by atmospheric moisture especially that accumulated over long distances.

The temperature difference between the two sensors should indicate how much water vapour is in the air. This might correspond to raindrops in the air but it might not so you would have to look further into the absorption spectra graphs of liquid vs water vapor (they seem to be different). It's a bit paradoxical in my mind since the reason rain is falling is because the atmosphere is unable to hold onto the water so the relationship is a bit unclear to me.

One such pair is the TS318-11C55 and TS318-1B0814 which are both available at Mouser as of the writing of this post. If you're specifically looking at moisture in the air, you might be able to find more suitable filters to specifically pick out the long infrared waves that are most absorbed by water.

---

You might also be able to use a large screen of some kind much like a giant low frequency microphone and read the frequency and impulse of the "strikes" detected against it. Maybe your window  with a transducer connected to it could be a sufficient detection screen.

Comment: Hum. Interesting. So then could just point it at the sky and note the sudden drop in temp to indicate that water droplets are getting in the way?

Comment: Not a drop in the sky temperature , a drop in the temperature difference between sky and ground. A clear sky measures very cold (kind of like the temperature of deep space) and allows lots of sun to heat up the ground. Both work together to make a huge temperature difference. Clouds are warmer than space and block sun so the ground heats up less making a smaller temperature difference. With water it's even lower. You would have to verify how reliable it is. There are sometimes weird hot rains on clearish sunny days.

Comment: You are ressentially looking for anything that makes the sky and ground closer in temperature so it might be worth it to sanity check a ground/sky temperature difference sensor it against a 5.5um vs 8-14um temperature comparison of a terrestrial distant object which looks directly at atmospheric moisture but might be trickier to interpret the reeadings.

Comment: Would the sensors be affected their internal temp? As the sun heats them during the day?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter as long as you are measuring a temperature difference. Thermopiles output a voltage proportional to difference between their internal temperature and whatever it is they are looking at. So as long as you are measuring temperature differences, and not absolute temperatures, you never need to worry about the internal temperature of the thermopile as long as the measurements are taken close in time with the same thermopile, or all thermopiles are at the same temperature when using multiple thermopiles. You will need an amplifier. I recommend AD8630 as a noninverting amp

Comment: Alright, I'm going to have to invest and try this.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the resistance between tracks on a PCB. The tracks should be gold plated for reliability. 
Here's an image of a commercial one. 
[image]

Comment: It won't stop detecting drops until the sensor drys out, which could take 15 minutes. That would be too long.

Comment: Add a fan (or blower) to blow air over the pcb when it detects rain. When the rain stops, the airflow will speed the evaporation (or blow off) the few drops left. When the conductivity of the array drops below a threshold, it's stopped raining and the fan can stop.

Comment: Or use a wiper that squeegees of the water. Problem is that those methods require a fair bit of power and additional mechanics. The car sensor is optical and requires the wiper to keep removing the drops. But is there another way that someone knows that I haven't yet found?

Comment: You could try a venus fly trap method. Venus fly traps can have their hairs triggered by rain drops and use a time-delay between multiple hairs method to try and not falsely close on something that's not a bug. You could do the reverse. Using a series of fiber optic loops as hairs is probably the most ideal way to go about it since they are much more sensitive than mechanical switches (or maybe even just one fiber optic loop that criss crosses back and forth)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the shape of your roof, or add a strip of metal near the open window, so no matter how hard it rains, nothing inside the house gets wet. Or replace the open bit of the window with a louvered insert.

A passive solution is always more reliable.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a fairly substantial solution. However in my country rain has been know to fall almost sideways when being blown hard by the wind. It's rare though